# How to get access to UAC prompt when running remote desktop application?

Tags: java, windows, operating-system, uac

I have developed my remote screen share software in java. It is working fine, but when there is use of UAC , the allow/disallow prompt comes on the screen but remote screen can not see it. So every time user has to allow it manually. I want to know how to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what the [`uiAccess`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851479.aspx) attribute in an application's assembly manifest was created for.

i'll blatently steal and quote from a the Microsoft AppCompat Guy's blog:

> ## [Using the uiAccess attribute of requestedExecutionLevel to Improve Applications Providing Remote Control of the Desktop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2009/10/15/using-the-uiaccess-attribute-of-requestedexecutionlevel-to-improve-applications-providing-remote-control-of-the-desktop.aspx)
>
> You have to elevate an application. When you do, you don’t see the UAC dialog – instead, the end user  does. Even if you decide to give the user the password (it happens), you then can’t control or even see the elevated application.
>
> Kind of makes it hard to be a helpdesk when that happens.
>
> Here are the 3 solutions that I have seen to this problem:
>
> - Do nothing. That’s what our solution did. It just failed every time elevation was involved.
> - Install a service. That’s what company X did. It requires the user to know an admin password, and that’s a problem for my customers
> - Run the application elevated. That’s what company Y did. It requires the user to know an admin password (a problem with my customers), and also won’t allow you to interact with any windows running at System integrity level (so an incomplete solution)
>
> Here’s what I wish all 3 had done:
>
> - Manifest with uiAccess = true
>
> most people don’t really understand what this is for, and the UAC manifest is typically just a copy/paste affair. But it pays for the remote desktop developer to pay attention to it. For any regular piece of software, you generally want to stay away from it – it’s dangerous, and sidesteps a significant security feature (UIPI). But if you are remoting the desktop, it’s precisely what you want – you need to be able to see everything!
>
> It’s dangerous enough, in fact, that we won’t allow you to set it without digitally signing your application. By default, you also have to have it installed in a secure location (such as Program Files). You can set a group policy to not require a secure location, but there is no option to not require a signature.
>
> However, once set up, it’s really powerful. You’ll be able to remote every possible kind of window – any integrity level at all. No more blank, unresponsive screens. Everything comes across, regardless of integrity level.

For the tl;dr version, here is the assemblymanifest with the `uiAccess=true` option:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?> 
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' 
 manifestVersion='1.0'> 
  <assemblyIdentity 
   version="1.0.0.0" 
   processorArchitecture="X86" 
   name="client" 
   type="win32" 
  /> 

  <description>Oh god not Java</description> 

  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3"> 
    <security> 
      <requestedPrivileges> 
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" 
         uiAccess="true"/> 
      </requestedPrivileges> 
    </security> 
  </trustInfo> 
</assembly>
```

Comment: Nice one. You've created a new user in SO just to answer your own question. Did it pay off?

Comment: @MoonStom You think i asked a question anonymously, six years after i first created an account on SO, so i could answer it myself six months later, without getting the accept, or an upvote? If i wanted to answer my own question, i would answer it myself - i've done so many times (even accepting my own answer). [You're encouraged on SO to answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). In this case, i probably answered the UAC related questions as i know all about UAC.

Comment: That's right. It is encouraged to answer your own questions. It's weird that the user who posted the question created a rubbish account just for asking this single question. However the time between the question and the answer is way off so ignore my comment. Thanks for the answer btw. Upvoted.

Comment: @MoonStom - my understanding is that *most* questions are asked by an anon user who is then never seen again, so that's hardly unusual.